# wp E-commerce featured product plugin with muliple option?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm Using  E-commerce featured product plugin.in this plugin we have a options to select a single product from product list but not able to select multiple options at same time.

---

so any suggest to improve this plugin?

Comment: Questions regarding wp-ecommerce are realy best left in the wp-ecommerce supprt group, you may find a more specific answer in there especially as "featured product" is a premium plugin...

Comment: thanks Martin...you have any direct links?

Comment: try this one, http://getshopped.org/forums/ or are you actually using this one http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce-featured-product/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the plugin http://jigoshop.com/, its free and has many possibilities.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jigoshop/